# How to do trigger which create a point after insert longitude and latitude?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, geospatial, spatial

I want to create trigger which after insert longitude and latitude  to table Vehicle create point from longitude latitude.

My trigger looks that

```
create trigger [dbo].[t_points]
on [dbo].[Vehicle]
after insert
as 
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Point AS GEOGRAPHY
    DECLARE @Longitude AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @Latitude AS FLOAT
        set @latitude = (select v.latitude from Vehicle v)
        set @longitude =    (select v.longitude from Vehicle v)

    if @latitude is not null and @Longitude is not null 
    begin
    set @Point = geography::Point(@latitude,@longitude,4326)
    update Vehicle set locationVehicle = @Point
    end
end
GO
```

but when I insert to my table values:

```
insert into Vehicle
  (idGroupVehicle, brand, model, maxRange, weight, maxSpeed, pricePerSale,
   latitude, longitude, locationName)
  values ('1', 'Xiaomi', 'Mijia M365 PRO', '45', '14', '1900', '25',
   '19.905203', '50.071597', 'Piastowska 49 Kraków')
```

I have error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Can someone explain me why I have this error and I can't insert to my table this value my trigger only check is latitude and longitude is not null create a point.

Comment: Why trigger ?  Just create a computed column ... preferably with persist.

Comment: Why does your trigger not reference the pseudo table `inserted`? Also, does your table `Vehicle` really only ever have one row?

Comment: I don't think you've grasped the concept of triggers. You are selecting all values from every row in `Vehicle` and essentially assigning a random value to each `@variable`; you're then updating all rows in the table with the value of `@point`.  `LocationVehicle` could be a computed column in this case, there's no need to try and reproduce essentially the same thing in a trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must query the `Inserted` pseudo table to get the inserted rows inside an insert trigger. This table might return several rows. Instead of looping through the rows, you can update the location column like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[t_points]
    ON [dbo].[Vehicle]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE v
    SET
        v.locationVehicle = geography::Point(i.latitude, i.longitude, 4326)
    FROM
        dbo.Vehicle v
        INNER JOIN inserted i
            ON v.idVehicle = i.idVehicle
    WHERE
        i.latitude IS NOT NULL AND
        i.longitude IS NOT NULL

END
```

<s>Assuming that `idGroupVehicle` is the primary key of the table. If it is not, replace it by the primary key (every table should have a primary key).</s>

**UPDATE** According to your comment I replaced `idGroupVehicle` by `idVehicle` in the join.

Comment: i have auto increment so my primery key is idVehicle

Comment: Thanks mate for help

Answer (score 2):

**Your trigger has fundamental flaws:**

- It does not take into account that there might be multiple (or no) rows in the statement
- It is not referencing the `inserted` pseudo-table, so the data it is pulling is from a random row
- It is writing back to the whole table, as there is no `where` filter

Instead a trigger would look like this:

```sql
create trigger [dbo].[t_points]
on [dbo].[Vehicle]
after insert
as 

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE v
SET locationVehicle = geography::Point(i.latitude, i.longitude,4326)
FROM inserted i
JOIN v ON v.id = i.id;  -- or whatever the primary key is

GO
```

---

**However:**

A much better solution is a simple computed column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Vehicle
    ADD locationVehicle AS (geography::Point(latitude, longitude, 4326));
```

Comment: i have record locationVehicle in my table i want trrigger becaouse i do the same trigger i table Customer and if Customer want to register in this system The customer will not have to think about how to type his point which srid must use

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, I believe, the way you are expecting triggers to work.

The error you are receiving is nothing to to with the trigger itself, you are declaring a variable and then trying to assign that variable a value from a sub query.

`select v.latitude from Vehicle v` - this does exactly what you might expect it to, being inside a "trigger" makes no difference, it will return a set of values, all rows in fact from table `vehicle` - hence the error "returned more than one row" - assigning a value to a variable expects a single value.

To do this with a trigger there is no need to assign values to any variables. What makes a trigger special is it makes available two *virtual* tables called `inserted` and `deleted` that contain rows affected only by the data modification that happened. Your insert could have inserted a single row or many, or none, and only these row(s) will be in the `inserted` table.

To update your column *only* for rows affected you would do the following

```
update v set
    v.LocationVehicle=geography::Point(v.latitude,v.longitude,4326)
from inserted i join Vehicle v on v.idGroupVehicle=i.idGroupVehicle
```

Having said that, you could try using a computed column instead which would accomplish the same thing

```
Alter table Vehicle add LocationVehicle as geography::Point(latitude,longitude,4326)
```