# How to do trigger which check the latitude and longitude and if latitude and longitude is correct we can insert to database?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, geospatial

i want to create trigger wchich will check the longitude and latitude before the insert to database  if longitude will be incorrect trigger print a message "wrong longitude longitude must be int the
interval so my trigger is that

```
create trigger t_point_betweenU2
on UserApp
INSTEAD OF insert 
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @latitude as float  
        declare @longitude as float 
        declare @Message Varchar(100)
        
        set @latitude = (select u.latitude from UserApp u)
        set @longitude =    (select u.longitude from UserApp u)
        
        Select  @latitude = i.latitude, @longitude = i.longitude
        from inserted i
        if((@latitude >= 19.7922354 and @latitude <= 20.2173455))
            begin
            Set @Message = 'This latitude is incorrect, latitude must be between 19.7922354 and 20.2173455'
                RaisError(@Message, 16, 1)
                RollBack
            end
        else if((@longitude>= 49.9676667 and @longitude <= 50.1261338))
        begin
            Set @Message = 'This longitude is incorrect , longitude must be between 49.9676667 and 50.1261338'
                RaisError(@Message, 16, 1)
                RollBack
            end
        
end
GO
```

but when i have this trigger i cant insert to my database
Can someone explain why i cant insert to database when i have thistrigger ?

Comment: Why use a `TRIGGER` and not a `CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: Also, your trigger *assumes* an `INSERT` contains only one row; that is simply not true.

Comment: If you do use a trigger, at least **learn** from the comments and suggests made in your past trigger questions.  And PRINT should not be used in a production trigger - triggers do not return resultsets or messages. They should only throw errors that need to be handled by the inserting process.

Comment: Pretty rude to expect people to [spend time answering you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67559239/14868997), and then completely ignore what they've said. Please take a good read of [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) then delete your trigger an use a constraint

Comment: ok i check the CONSTRAINT and in this situation is better than trigger thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, don't use a `TRIGGER` at all, just use a couple of `CONSTRAINT`s:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserApp ADD CONSTRAINT chk_latitude CHECK (latitude >= 19.7922354 and latitude <= 20.2173455);
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserApp ADD CONSTRAINT chk_longitude CHECK (longitude >= 49.9676667 and longitude <= 50.1261338);
```